# Plotly JS - Assign custom value per point?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

In PlotlyJS, I want to associate a unique ID with each of my point pairs because I need to use this value to calculate something post selection. There is a customData attribute, but it assigns the entire list of ids to each point.

My data list is:

```
x = [1, 4, 5, 3, 6, 3]
y = [2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4]
```

ids = [id1, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6] // Each id corresponds to the value pair

I can't use the combination of the x, y values to fetch the id, because if you notice, my value pairs duplicate at index 3 & 5 (x=3, y=4) so I need to associate the id before hand.

Any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. There is something called an 'ids' property which is only applicable for scatter plots, which is what I am using. I have to assign the ids array to this property, and Plotly internally maps these ids to the pair appropriately based on the index. So the indexes are very important.

Example:

```
var subject = ['Moe','Larry','Curly','Moe','Larry','Curly','Moe','Larry','Curly','Moe','Larry','Curly']
var score = [1,6,2,8,2,9,4,5,1,5,2,8]
var ids = ['Curly1', 'Moe1', 'Larry1', etc.] // <= Has to be a string array 
var data = [{
    type: 'scatter',
    x: subject,
    y: score,
    ids: ids, // <= Here
    mode: 'markers',
    transforms: [{
        type: 'groupby',
        groups: subject,
        styles: [
            {target: 'Moe', value: {marker: {color: 'blue'}}},
            {target: 'Larry', value: {marker: {color: 'red'}}},
            {target: 'Curly', value: {marker: {color: 'black'}}}
        ]
    }]
}]

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data)
```

(Example from the docs)
https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/scatter/#scatter-ids

Now in any of the events that allow you to brush points, each point will have the respective id attached. This allows you to refer to that point uniquely, in my case I had to make an AJAX call for some data.